# How to find which line we are reading using a StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

Hi i was wondering how to know the position of the line which we are reading using streamreader.
For example

```
FileStream strstream = new FileStream("text.txt",FileMode.open,FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(strstream);
 while (!strReader.EndOfStream)
 {

if(strReader.Readline() == "start")
{
Console.WriteLine("Found at line{0}",strReaderCurrentLine)
}
}
```

How can we get the streamReaders current position?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Define a variable int lineNumber, and increase it wehenever your read a line. StreamReader does not keep track of the number of lines it read for understandable reasons.

Comment: Is there no other way to find the streamReaders current position?

Comment: Position and line position are different things. StreamReader keeps the current character position internally (the char offset from the starting point of the creation of the StreamReader). But even getting that private "charPos" variable with reflection will not give you the number of lines that have been read

Comment: Nope, just make youre own class as a wrapper around is of count the files youreself